# Replace switch with dimmer for lights on two fans

Tags: ceiling-fan

The two lights are wired to one switch. The fans are wired to the other switch.  Can I install a dimmer just to control the lights and use a one pole since there is only one switch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Turn off the power and remove the two wires from the old switch and hook them up to the two terminals of the dimmer.